# Placing text on the outside of a curve (Tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I looked through the Tikz manual before posting but couldn't find anything on this. I want to draw a spiral which has nodes with anchored text along the path. I currently have

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,color=red,domain=4*pi:8*pi,samples=200,smooth] plot (xy polar cs:angle=\x r,radius= {0.1*\x});

\foreach \x/\xtext  in {{27*pi/6}/Text on outside,{33*pi/6}/now on inside =(}
  \draw (1.0027*\x r : 0.1*\x) circle (2pt) node[above] {\xtext};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Unfortunately I can't upload an image of the result of the above code (I encountered an error upon upload every time I tried).

Specifying `node[above]` means that the text will appear on the inside for half of the spiral but on the outside for the other half. I could (and might have to) specify each the position of each node anchor manually, but I was wondering if there's a way to ensure the anchor is always on the outside (or inside).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @HarishKumar Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @cfr: `I could (and might have to) specify each the position of each node anchor manually, but I was wondering if there's a way to ensure the anchor is always on the outside (or inside).` This sentence made me think that I may be too impulsive. :) And then I ran out of time (had to start to the college).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to specify a number of points, it might be easier to test the value of `\x` and determine the position of the node's label accordingly. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=20pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,color=red,domain=4*pi:8*pi,samples=200,smooth] plot (xy polar cs:angle=\x r,radius= {0.1*\x});

\foreach \x/\xtext  in {{9/2}/Text on outside,{11/2}/Still outside,{13/2}/Yet more outside text,{15/2}/Further outside text}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\xresult{ (mod(\x,2) > 1) ? "below" : "above"  }
  \draw (1.0027*pi*\x r : 0.1*pi*\x) circle (2pt) node[\xresult] {\xtext};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: automated label positioning]

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. I'll need to play around with it a bit to fully understand it, but I've no doubt that it's possible now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JamesMachin Glad it helped. Let me know if you have a question about it. It is basically just using the maths parser of PGF.

Answer (score 4):

Just a small extension to [cfr's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262064/23215). The anchor for the node can be set to the angle of the spiral plus `pi` for arbitrary angles:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick, color=red]
  plot [domain=4*pi:8*pi, samples=200, smooth] (\x r:0.1*\x);

\foreach \x in {16,...,32}
  \fill (pi r * \x/4 : pi/10*\x/4) circle [radius=1pt] 
     node [anchor=pi r * \x/4 + pi r, inner sep=2] {\tiny$\frac{\x}{4}\pi$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]